# MongoDB - How to query unique fields in many documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a db with 80,000 documents in it and each document has a field named Location like below:

**Location: "82 Some Street  | Gautham PS M1M 1M1"**

This address field is repeated in many documents. I want to do a query that does a count of the documents with unique addresses only in Location field. How to do that?

So even though I have 80,000 documents, probably only 50,000 of them are unique and other 30,000 have the repeat address so I want to get that 50,000 count accurately.

I guess first, I have to search all the address and then take out the repeats and then do a count?

I tried distinct command but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Location",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      count: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "uniqueAddresses"
  }
])
```

In this query, first, we group the documents by `address` and calculate the `counts`. Next, we only keep the counts where the value is 1. Then using the `$count` operator we calculate the count.

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xIoNul25Dvs)

Try this as well:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "unique": {
        "$addToSet": "$statusCode"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "count": {
        "$size": "$unique"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yio_M6A2rZ_)

Comment: I don't see the "Location" field in your example. My field named "Location" has the address. Also, should I copy / paste this in mongosh and it should work? I tried and it didn't give me any output. No errors or results of a count.

Comment: @bruceb updated the answer. The query will work, just make sure that the field name in "_id" matches with what is present in your database

Comment: Thanks. Does this print a number only or many addresses? Idea is that it should only print a number and that would be something like 50,000 for me because I have probably around 30,000 none unique addresses in my list. I am only interested to see a count number and not any other display.

Comment: It will only give count @bruceb. You can run the query by going to the playground link. The output will be something like this in your case: `{ uniqueAddresses: 50000 }`

Comment: Works great. Thanks. Needs a semicolon at the end if running it inside mongosh.

Comment: how to also print each unique field's content too along with the count?

Comment: You can try something like this @bruceb https://mongoplayground.net/p/hJF5j-WLKHQ

Comment: Thanks. Something is not counting right. I have multiple status codes but count shows only two. Query and data screen shot posted here: 
 https://imgur.com/a/JOQ261O

Comment: Instead of the image can you share a playground link as I shared in the answer and comments.

Comment: Here is playground sample giving same result: https://mongoplayground.net/p/85NCnajTAIx

Comment: Added another query @bruceb.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Aggregation framework:

- `$group` with `$addToSet` - to get all the unique locations and add them to the `unique_locations` array.
- `$project` with `$size` - to get the total count of unique locations by calculating the length of the `unique_locations` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "unique_locations": {
        "$addToSet": "$Location"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "total_unique": {
        "$size": "$unique_locations"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DR_xhGOzNIu)

Comment: My field name is "Location". I don't see you use that in your example. The end result should be just a number which is a count of number of documents with unique addresses and nothing else displayed.

Comment: it does not work with this example, why? Count should be 7: https://mongoplayground.net/p/419V7HTE3ZW

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Answer (score -2):

- Maybe you should try;

```
  let location="82 Some Street | Gautham PS M1M 1M1";

  const getUniqueLocations = await YourDB.find({Location : {$ne: location}}).countDocuments();
```

countDocuments() returns the count.

Comment: I don't know the addresses. I want to know *count of the unique addresses in Location field. Your example seems to not do that.

Comment: - Instead of address use location as the field name.
- Above code edited.

Comment: Also, you should have clearly mentioned what is your field name.

Comment: Have you found the right solution?

Comment: Yeah, posted above.